# How to retrieve image column from SharePoint List using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

How to retrieve image column from  SharePoint List using REST API [image]

Comment: Why REST and not JSOM or other options? i.e. What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should know `Hyperlink` = `Picture`. So the way of getting Hyperlink is the way of getting Picture column. You just need to make `GET` request to the following `URL`.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Your List Title')/Items?$select=Image
```

Response will like following

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "cba8c563-bc0d-4f2b-91d5-a851b3f35a4f",
                "uri": "https://yourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'aaafa7f3-35e8-4cab-8a9f-ee6864c19747')/Items(3)",
                "etag": "\"1\"",
                "type": "SP.Data.ModalLogsListItem"
            },
            "Image": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.FieldUrlValue"
                },
                "Description": "image",
                "Url": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwIhm.png"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

If you have time, then pass some time with this [article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: +1 for your [blog article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API), nice and condensed reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everyday I go to your profile and learn from your answers. BIG fan of yours

Comment: My personal favorite [Drag Drop Edit View](http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Drag_Drop_Columns_in_the_EditView_Page)

Comment: Great Sharing........!!!

Comment: Now back to OPs question.. I still wonder why he specifically asks for REST.. only time can tell :-)

Comment: hahaha! could be for REST as he has mentioned in Title and tag

Comment: Please Tell How to append the "Url": "http://i.stack.imgur.com/mwIhm.png" into div

Comment: It's a different question. But you can try following

 $('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/mwIhm.png"/>')

Comment: Does not work for me. I got a column that is named Image1 (I checked ist internalname) and I can't get it using _api/web/lists(guid'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')/Items?$select=Image1. Am I missing something ?

Comment: What's the error? @frenchone

Comment: It doesn't know about my column name 'Image1'. Even if I'm sure it exists (because my solution is working)

Comment: @AtishDipongkor-MVP is this answer still relevant today with SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get Atish Dipongkor's solution to work

Sharepoint just sucks.

You can get a geolocation field which is a "complex" object (=has subproperties : altitude, longitude,latitude)

```
    "place": {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.FieldGeolocationValue"
      },
      "Altitude": 0,
      "Latitude": 48.38884,
      "Longitude": -40.48393,
      "Measure": 0
    },
```

But you can't get image field which should have exactly the same structure (title,url) !
Why is that ? This is just plain stupid. This won't save bandwidth or anything.

On the contrary, because of this stupid design you need to do N subqueries (one for each of your result) to get the image for each of you result.

So you need a first pass to search results
/_api/web/lists(guid'**the_guid**')/items?$filter=...

Then you need to iterate EVERY result to get the image
/_api/web/lists(guid'**the_guid**')/items(xx)/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=your image column names

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852997/retrieve-publishing-image-field-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-csom

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add(C# code) if you want to retrieve image url from list with Hyperlink column. Please see below-

```
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite("Site Url"))
        {
           using( SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
           {
               SPList list = web.Lists["CountryList"];
              SPListItemCollection items =list.Items;
               foreach(SPListItem f in items)
               {
                   SPFieldUrlValue field = new SPFieldUrlValue(f["Image"].ToString());
                   Console.WriteLine("Image Url:" + field.Url);
                   Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852997/retrieve-publishing-image-field-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-csom)

Where I added the following solution:

I found a way to get all data in a single call: use the [RenderListDataAsStream POST REST call](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#retrieve-items-as-a-stream):

```
this._webAbsoluteUrl +
"/_api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/RenderListDataAsStream?
@listUrl=%27%2Fsites%2F<scName>%2Flists%2F<listUrlName>%27";
```

It gives all simple text field data, can be used for more complex fields such as managed metadata & lookup fields, but more importantly in this case, it gives you the url of the image that was used for the Publishing Image column.

You do need to parse it from this structure:

```
"<div dir="" class="ms-rtestate-field"><img alt="" src="/sites/<scName>/SiteAssets/<myImageOnSharepoint>.jpg" style="BORDER&#58;0px solid;" /></div>"
```

Code sample (SPFx with TypeScript):

```
const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
requestHeaders.append("Content-type", "application/json");
requestHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");

var body =
{ parameters:
  {
    DatesInUtc: "true"
  }
};

const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: requestHeaders
};
const queryUrlGetAllItems: string =
  this._webAbsoluteUrl +
  `/_api/web/GetList(@listUrl)/RenderListDataAsStream?@listUrl=%27%2Fsites%2F<scName>%2Flists%2F<listUrlName>%27`;

return this._webPartContext.spHttpClient
  .post(queryUrlGetAllItems, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions)
  .then((response: any) => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(JSON.stringify(response)));
    }
  })
  .then((data: any) => {
    if (data) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.Row.length; i++) {
        let item = data.Row[i];
        // ... process data
      }
    }
    // ... return value
  });
```